# Redux saga with firestore combination with react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, redux-saga

I am working in one project that using Redux saga with firestore and in a combination with react native.it is working fine but i have one issues with firestore response, because when i used yield call function its always return in promise and i used yield put to put data and its working fine with promise data but i need to use data with resolve value, and in this scenario put function call before resolve data. if i used delay than working fine but without delay not getting.

I am not much aware about redux saga so can any one help me out of this situation.

Here is code for reference, in this below code `yield put` call before data resolve and if i put `yield delay()` before `yield put` then working fine, but without delay function i have facing issues.

```
var resultData = [ ]; 
var resonseResult = yield call(Api.callWebservice) resonseResult.then(function(items){ 
  console.log("resonseResult",item) 
  resultData = items 
}) 
yield put({type: FETCH_DATA, resultData: resultData})
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: Here is code for reference, in this below code yield put call before data resolve and if i put yield delay() before yield put then working fine, but without delay function i have facing issues.   

                                    
var resultData = [ ];

var resonseResult = yield call(Api.callWebservice)

resonseResult.then(function(items){
   console.log("resonseResult",item)
   resultData = items
}) 

yield put({type: FETCH_DATA, resultData: resultData})